# From TransactionProxyFactoryBean to a Declarative transaction management?

Tags: spring, transactions

I want to migrate from old style of transaction management with TransactionProxyFactoryBean to a Declarative transaction management recommended by spring.
So that will be possible to avoid exceptions with transactions that appear from time to time.

This is my configuration xml file:

```
<beans  xmlns=...>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="prof" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <import resource="prof-dao-spring.xml" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="baseTransactionProxy" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
        <property name="transactionManager">
          <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
          <props>
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            ...
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
          </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ProfileService" parent="baseTransactionProxy">
     <property name="target">
      <bean class="tv.clever.hibernate.service.ProfileService"></bean>
     </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`ProfileService` looks like:

```
@Component
public class ProfileService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("baseDAO")
protected BaseDAO baseDAO;

private static ProfileService profileService;

public ProfileService() {

    setProfileService(this);
}

public void setProfileService(ProfileService ps) {

            profileService = ps;
}

public void save(final Collection transientObjects) {

    baseDAO.save(transientObjects);
}

 ...
}
```

From where do I need to start?

Comment: What do you want to do? Use annotations i.e. `@Transactional`? Or still remain using XML? Small tip instead of `@Component` I would suggest using `@Service` to mark your services classes and `@Repository` for your daos. What is the contraption with setting a static reference to yourself, this would have my alarm bells ringing... Your current setup is also duplicating all beans? You have component-scanning and manual configuration, you are basically creating 2 instances (excluding the proxy) for each bean.

Comment: Yes, I want an `Annotation style transaction` like in this example (1. Annotation style transaction): http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html The difference is that I use the Hibernate Framework `HibernateTransactionManager`

Comment: Which transaction manager doesn't matter.

Comment: The technology doesn't matter transaction management is the same regardless the use of JPA, Hibernate, JTA of plain JDBC. It simply doesn't matter it is just a matter of wiring the correct transaction manager to the transaction stuff, the rest is all the same. That is the whole point of declarative transaction management that it doesn't matter what you use, it remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to use annotations slap a `@Transactional` on your service class, add `<tx:annotation-driven />` to your configuration and remove the `TransactionalProxyFactoryBean` declaration and all beans using that as a parent.

Additional pro-tips:

1. Use `@Service` for service classes and `@Repository` for daos
2. `<context:annotation-config />` is implied by `<context:component-scan />`

Your service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProfileService { ... }
```

Configuration

```
<beans  xmlns=...>

    <context:component-scan base-package="prof" />

    <import resource="prof-dao-spring.xml" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Restart application.

Comment: For understanding transaction pitfalls I would recommend this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html